# How to use select2 v4.03 and AngularJS together

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, angularjs-select2

I would like to use **AngularJs** and **Select2 v4.03** without adding any directives. I've researched that it's possible now with the new version of `select2`.

For now I've been using `ui-select` but it's only supporting the old version of `select2` and I'd like to use the new `select2` features in my application.

Can anyone please help me how is it possible to use `select2` with AngularJS directly (maybe via `ng-model`)?

Comment: It's a jQuery plugin. You still need to wrap it in directive.

Comment: @dfsq What do you mean exactly by this? Can you please elaborate it in an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select2` is a jQuery plugin which has a completely different approach than AngularJS native widgets (in angular these are directives) which are designed to work the angular-way from the beginning. So normally it is a good idea to use native directives if you can. If you don't find a good replacement, then you also can use jQuery elements, but you have to wrap them in an angular directive to tweak them and make them work the angular-way. This is what projects like `ui-select` do.

So if the newer `select2` is still not available on `ui-select` you can wait until it is implemented. Or search for another wrapper... Or, search for a native alternative. If you haven't already I would recommend you to take a look at [oi-select](http://tamtakoe.github.io/oi.select/), for example, which I find quite good and flexible.

*Update*

Sorry, I just checked, and the `select2` implementation from [ui-select](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/) is a native angularJS implementation of the jQuery version and not just a wrapper.